# Non-Rectangular Image GWT Button

Tags: gwt, button, imagebutton

I am trying to create a custom GWT Button based on an image.

I have an image that is not rectangular, something like this:
     [image: Yellow Triangle Image]

1. Now, I want the **click-able** area to only work inside the visible parts of the image (non-transparent areas).  This would mean that it's possible for someone using the button to click in the transparent corners of the image (Button) and not trigger the click event on the Button.  Is this possible without having to create a custom widget (and the HTML to go with it)?
2. I would like to make a set of these non-rectangular buttons, in which there would be other buttons that would inter-connect with this one (their visible edges will bump right up against eachother, in sort of an inter-locking pattern), sort of like this:
   [image: Inter-Locking Triangles]

   That's a very complex example, mine wouldn't be as big/many but the concept holds: inter-locking buttons of custom shape each being an individual button.  These buttons would not be generated statically, but grow based on action.

Is this even possible?  I have no clue where to begin.  The 2nd picture (pyramid inter-locking triangles) is more complex than what I'm envisioning, but the concept holds.  The reason it's more complex is because ultimately I would only be inter-locking buttons Horizontally (think of the 2nd row near the top of the pyramid picture, *the 3 triangles from left to right*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple Map Widget for `<map>`, `<area>` tags.

```
public class ImageMap extends Widget implements HasMouseDownHandlers {

  private MapElement mapElement;

  public ImageMap() {
    mapElement = Document.get().createMapElement();
    setElement(mapElement);
  }

  public String getImgName() {
    return mapElement.getName();
  }

  public void setImgName(String imgName) {
    mapElement.setName(imgName);
  }

  public void addMapArea(AreaElement area) {
    mapElement.appendChild(area);
  }

  public HandlerRegistration addMouseDownHandler(MouseDownHandler handler) {
    return addDomHandler(handler, MouseDownEvent.getType());
  }

}
```

The creation code:

```
AreaElement area = Document.get().createAreaElement();
area.setShape("rect");
area.setCoords("389,250,491,502");
area.setHref("#main");

imageMap = new ImageMap();
imageMap.setImg("frontPage");
imageMap.addMapArea(area);
imageMap.addMouseDownHandler(this);
```

or can use SVG image with raphaeljs for more complex effects (see [raphaelgwt](http://code.google.com/p/raphaelgwt/)). It's better than map-area solution.

Comment: This might work, wow.  I notice in the example you give it "rect" as a shape for the AreaElement.  I'm assuming I could pass in a polygon and just define a list of points (csv) in setCoords() right?  Is this the list of possible shapes I can pass in to the area.setShape() method - http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/objects.html#adef-shape ?  I may have some more complex sizing operations to do since I plan on overlaying text on each of these (thus longer text = wider area).

Comment: **Also**: I'm also curious, does this do a convex hull operation on the points given? I can envision telling the area to setShape("poly") and giving it 5 points, with the 5th point inside the given 4. I imagine it assumes a convex hull on the points, and not some weird shape, or when you specify the points, does order matter?

Comment: Yes, you should use "poly", coord's order matters. For polygonal regions I use GIMP's Web->Image Map filter to paint areas right over images and get correct coords.

Comment: Ok, looks like this means I'll have to use an image (or series of images) to grow the inter-connecting buttons dynamically. I'm not sure how else I would do it.  After looking at this more, it's not ideal but I think it may be the easiest way given alternatives (which there are not many of).  Since no one else has responded I'll give you credit for the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: thnx. Map's areas are the simplest and oldest way to do what you want. Also pay attention to SVG animated with Raphael (or other JS library). You can create amazing shapes like on [link](http://www.researchgate.net/).