# GWT ImageMap, how to register a Mouse Handler to an Area Element?

Tags: gwt

Typical ImageMap application:

- I have a SVG/PNG map with regions (e.g., US with states).
- I have the polygon coordinates of the regions.
- I want to register mouse handlers (over, out, down) with behavior that depend upon the region.

I am struggling to get the area element's handlers to fire.

Current state:

- I have loaded the image, created & associated the image to a MapElement and added the AreaElement as shown in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6674461/1143684).
- Following the same pattern as [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6674461/1143684), I created an ImageMap widget (same as in link) and an ImageMapArea widges, the latter wrapping an AreaElement, see sample code below.
- I have also added an area property representing its ID so I can easily use the same handler for all the AreaElement widgets.
- The handlers I register on the ImageMapArea widgets do not fire.  Why not?  What is the proper way to accomplish this dynamic behavior dependent on each AreaElement region?
- On other sites, I see area element attributes like `onmousedown=myJsOnMouseDownFunction()`, `onmouseover`, etc.  I am looking for a GWT approach to implement the same dynamic behavior.  I have the handlers implemented in java code (see example below).  How do I plug them in to the Area elements or ImageMapArea widgets?

Here is my `ImageMapArea` wrapping AreaElement:

```
public class ImageMapArea extends Widget implements HasMouseDownHandlers, HasMouseOverHandlers, HasMouseOutHandlers
{
  private AreaElement areaElement;

  public ImageMapArea() {
    areaElement = Document.get().createAreaElement();
    super.setElement(areaElement);
  }

  public AreaElement getAreaElement() { return areaElement; }

  @Override
  public HandlerRegistration addMouseDownHandler(final MouseDownHandler handler)
  {
    return super.addDomHandler(handler, MouseDownEvent.getType());
  }

  @Override
  public HandlerRegistration addMouseOutHandler(final MouseOutHandler handler)
  {
    return super.addDomHandler(handler, MouseOutEvent.getType());
  }

  @Override
  public HandlerRegistration addMouseOverHandler(final MouseOverHandler handler)
  {
    return super.addDomHandler(handler, MouseOverEvent.getType());
  }
}
```

Here is how I weave it together:

```
// Setup ImageMap.
Image map = new Image("MyMap.svg");
ImageMap imageMap = new ImageMap();
map.getElement().setAttribute("usemap", "#" + "dynmap");
imageMap.setName("dynmap");

// Add area.
ImageMapArea area = new ImageMapArea();
area.getAreaElement().setShape("poly");
area.getAreaElement().setCoords(<string representing the coordinates of area>);
area.getAreaElement().setPropertyInt("aid", 1); // ID to dynamically identify the area element.
area.getAreaElement().setAlt("This is region #1");
area.getAreaElement().setTitle("This is region #1"); // Tooltip works so above coordinates are good.
area.setStylePrimaryName("area");
area.addStyleDependentName("out");
// Add handlers -- those that do not fire.
area.addMouseDownHandler(handlerDown);
area.addMouseOutHandler(handlerOut);
area.addMouseOverHandler(handlerOver);

// Handler example.
final MouseDownHandler handlerDown = new MouseDownHandler()
{
  @Override
  public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event)
  {
    final Object source = event.getSource();
    final ImageMapArea area = (ImageMapArea) source; // A breakpoint here never stopped.
    if (area != null)
    {
      final int areaIndex = area.getAreaElement().getPropertyInt("aid");
      if (areaIndex != areaSelectedIndex)
      {
        area.removeStyleDependentName("over");
        area.addStyleDependentName("selected");
        areaSelectedIndex = areaIndex;
        ... // Other dynamic actions that depend upon the area/region triggering this event.
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why handlers in my questions don't fire, but getting inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6906746/1143684) leading to [this ImageMapArea implementation](http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=kWOfU2hSdlSFCuQtoBS3rznR0vo&cid=3AMJ1b2UxWo&s=gwt%20ImageMap&fp=12753&mp&projSelected=true#L0), I found an approach that works: the trick is to resort to native javascript (JSNI) to set the `onmouse` call backs -- [JSNI Google Doc here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).

In case anyone finds it useful as I would have, here is my updated version of `ImageMapArea` to setup the native handlers.

```
public class ImageMapArea extends Widget
{
  private AreaElement areaElement;
  private ArrayList<Hook> onMouseDownHooks = null;
  private ArrayList<Hook> onMouseOutHooks = null;
  private ArrayList<Hook> onMouseOverHooks = null;

  public ImageMapArea() {
    areaElement = Document.get().createAreaElement();
    super.setElement(areaElement);
    this.setupNativeHandlers(areaElement);
  }

  public AreaElement getAreaElement() { return areaElement; }

  public void addMouseDownHandler(final Hook handler)
  {
    if (onMouseDownHooks == null)
      onMouseDownHooks = new ArrayList<Hook>(1);
    onMouseDownHooks.add(handler);
  }

  public void addMouseOutHandler(final Hook handler)
  {
    if (onMouseOutHooks == null)
      onMouseOutHooks = new ArrayList<Hook>(1);
    onMouseOutHooks.add(handler);
  }

  public void addMouseOverHandler(final Hook handler)
  {
    if (onMouseOverHooks == null)
      onMouseOverHooks = new ArrayList<Hook>(1);
    onMouseOverHooks.add(handler);
  }

  private void onMouseDown()
  {
    if (onMouseDownHooks != null && !onMouseDownHooks.isEmpty())
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < onMouseDownHooks.size(); ++i)
      {
        final Hook hook = onMouseDownHooks.get(i);
        hook.execute();
      }
    }
  }

  private void onMouseOut()
  {
    if (onMouseOutHooks != null && !onMouseOutHooks.isEmpty())
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < onMouseOutHooks.size(); ++i)
      {
        final Hook hook = onMouseOutHooks.get(i);
        hook.execute();
      }
    }
  }

  private void onMouseOver()
  {
    if (onMouseOverHooks != null && !onMouseOverHooks.isEmpty())
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < onMouseOverHooks.size(); ++i)
      {
        final Hook hook = onMouseOverHooks.get(i);
        hook.execute();
      }
    }
  }

  private native void setupNativeHandlers(final AreaElement elem) /*-{
    var self = this;
    elem.onmousedown = function(){
        self.@bkg.gwt.resources.client.widget.ImageMapArea::onMouseDown()();
    };
    elem.onmouseout = function(){
        self.@bkg.gwt.resources.client.widget.ImageMapArea::onMouseOut()();
    };
    elem.onmouseover = function(){
        self.@bkg.gwt.resources.client.widget.ImageMapArea::onMouseOver()();
    };
  }-*/;
}
```

`Hook` above is nothing else than `Scheduler.ScheduledCommand`.

Everything works the same as before except the handlers are implemented in call-back commands instead of GWT mouse handlers; the above `ImageMapArea` takes care of setting up the native JSNI call backs.

An improvement would be to define the `Hook.execute` with an `ImageMapArea` argument so all areas can share the same Hook call back object.